# Message queue for two cpp file with windows API

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, c++11, winapi

To send the message in the Queue from one source file and get the message in another source file.I read the docs from Microsoft and try to implement as below

test2.c - post the message
main.c - get the Message

Testing1: If i execute the same code in single file that get executed and i receive the data

Testing : Same code is written in two separate file "if (msg.message == WM_YOUR_MESSAGE)" these statement does not get satisfied.

test2.h

```cpp
typedef struct
{
    int SomeData1;
    int SomeData2;
    int SomeDataN;
} MessageData;

/* Unique IDs for Window messages to exchange between the worker and the 
GUI thread. */

#define WM_YOUR_MESSAGE   ( WM_USER + 3 )

void __cdecl ThreadProc(void* aArg);
```

test2.c

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "malloc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <test2.h>

volatile DWORD ThreadID_GUI;

void __cdecl ThreadProc(void* aArg)
{
    MessageData* data;

    for (;; )
    {
        Sleep(500);

        /* Allocate memory for a new message data structure */
        data = (MessageData*)malloc(sizeof(*data));

        /* Initialize the message data structure with some information to transfer
           to the GUI thread. */
        data->SomeData1 = 1234;
        data->SomeData2 = 4567;
        data->SomeDataN = 7894;

       PostThreadMessage(ThreadID_GUI, WM_YOUR_MESSAGE, 0, (LPARAM)data);
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "malloc.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include<test2.h>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
   {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

// TODO: Place code here.

ThreadID_GUI = GetCurrentThreadId();

/* Start some background thread */
_beginthread(ThreadProc, 0, 0);

// Initialize global strings
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTMESSAGEQUEUE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

// Perform application initialization:
if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
{
    return FALSE;
}

HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTMESSAGEQUEUE));

MSG msg;

// Main message loop:
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
        /* STEP 3: React on the message sent from the foreign thread */
        if (msg.message == WM_YOUR_MESSAGE)
        {
            MessageData* tmp = (MessageData*)msg.lParam;

                if (tmp->SomeData1 == 1234) {
                printf("someData\n");
            }
            /* Free the data structure associated to the message */
            free(tmp);
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, 
MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_CLIENTMQ));
wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_CLIENTMQ);
wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, 
MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, 
nullptr);

if (!hWnd)
{
  return FALSE;
}

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

return TRUE;
}

 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
 lParam)
 {
 switch (message)
 {
case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, 
         About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}

 // Message handler for about box.
 INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM 
 lParam)
{
 UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
 switch (message)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

case WM_COMMAND:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
    {
        EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
    }
    break;
}
return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Please show complete code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: this is the complete code which i am trying right now on VIsual Studio

Comment: No, it isn't. Test.h and test2.cpp are missing.

Comment: sorry for that i have updated the code

Comment: This is still incomplete. I don't see `windows.h` included somewhere.

Comment: `test2.cpp` should be `test2.c` because you are doing a **C** project.

Comment: `test2.c` should include `windows.h` and `test2.h`. Before posting code, you should really try it!  Copying/pasting partial code from your actual application is really a bad idea and discourage the one who try to help you.

Comment: There is also a missing `.rc` file.

Comment: `#include <process.h>` missing in main.c.

Comment: `MyRegisterClass` code is missing.

Comment: Please take the time to create a new project in Visual Studio, copy/paste the code you show here and resolve **ALL errors** and **ALL warnings**. Then edit your question to show **full code** that I can copy/paste here to check. And Pleaaase read [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And probably when you have done all that, your code will work...

Comment: i have included everthing , probably the code was having #include <process.h> and MyRegisterClass but i have not pasted in the forum. Also there are no warning and error . I have checked the code when i debug the code "msg.message == WM_YOUR_MESSAGE" this condition is not satisfied. My aim to store the data in message queue from one source file and to get the data in another source file in Windows. I wanted to confirm PostThreadMessage and GetMessage is the correct API?

Comment: The code does not compile. *main.c* tries to access `ThreadID_GUI`, but that identifier isn't known to *main.c*. Besides, custom application-local message IDs should be in th `WM_APP+x` range, not `WM_USER`.

Comment: Yes i am missing "ThreadID_GUI, but that identifier isn't known to main.c. " that part but i really dont know how to do i implement that?. I will fix this WM_APP+x

Comment: There are still missing parts. Read again **all** my comments. And please take the time to create a new project in Visual Studio, copy/paste the code you show here and resolve ALL errors and ALL warnings. What you posted is not enough, nor in correct order (or missing declarations). The code you post is all we have to help you. As far as I can see until now, there is no fundamental error. The issue is in some detail somewhere and we need **all** code. Don't forget the .rc file!

Comment: You should complete the request quickly and correctly or the risk is high that your question will be closed...

Comment: Since you are posting a thread message, there's no reason to have a window at all. Just remove all of that code. The resulting [mcve] should not require any vertical scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After filling all the missing information in your source, and removing useless code, I have your code working.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include "test2.h"

HINSTANCE hInst;
LPCWSTR szWindowClass = L"Piu";
LPCWSTR szTitle = L"Title";

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM
    lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
            /*
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd,
                About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
            */
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(wcex));

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    /*
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_CLIENTMQ));
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_CLIENTMQ);
    */
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, 0, hInstance,
        NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    ThreadID_GUI = GetCurrentThreadId();

    /* Start some background thread */
    _beginthread(ThreadProc, 0, 0);

    // Initialize global strings
//    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
//    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_TESTMESSAGEQUEUE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

//    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_TESTMESSAGEQUEUE));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* STEP 3: React on the message sent from the foreign thread */
        if (msg.message == WM_YOUR_MESSAGE)
        {
            MessageData* tmp = (MessageData*)msg.lParam;

            if (tmp->SomeData1 == 1234) {
                printf("someData\n");
            }
            /* Free the data structure associated to the message */
            free(tmp);
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;

}
```

test2.c:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "test2.h"

volatile DWORD ThreadID_GUI;

void __cdecl ThreadProc(void* aArg)
{
    MessageData* data;

    for (;; )
    {
        Sleep(500);

        /* Allocate memory for a new message data structure */
        data = (MessageData*)malloc(sizeof(*data));

        /* Initialize the message data structure with some information to transfer
           to the GUI thread. */
        data->SomeData1 = 1234;
        data->SomeData2 = 4567;
        data->SomeDataN = 7894;

        PostThreadMessage(ThreadID_GUI, WM_YOUR_MESSAGE, 0, (LPARAM)data);
    }
}
```

test2.h

```
typedef struct
{
    int SomeData1;
    int SomeData2;
    int SomeDataN;
} MessageData;

/* Unique IDs for Window messages to exchange between the worker and the
GUI thread. */

#define WM_YOUR_MESSAGE   ( WM_USER + 3 )

void __cdecl ThreadProc(void* aArg);
extern volatile DWORD ThreadID_GUI;
```

I removed menu and icons so there is no .rc file.

Comment: I have one more doubt , as PostMessage is in different thread and GetMessage in different thread. Is it possible to do _beginthread(ThreadProc, 0, 0); in the file where PostMessage is there in my case it is test2.c.

Comment: You can use PostMessage from any thread and the message will be retrieved in the context of the thread executing GetMessage (The main thread in your case). PostMessage is one of the best way to pass information between threads without the need of critical section, mutex or other fancy code to protect shared data. Something important: thread context is **totally** independent of how the code is split in several sources. Splitting code in several source is handled by the compiler while thread context is handled by the OS at run time.

Comment: How do i check whether the Message Queue is full or how many exactly the message has posted

Comment: You can use [PeekMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew) to fetch (with or without removing from the queue) one message from the queue (The top one according to a filter you pass) or [GetMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage) to wait for a message and read it.